# Matching fixed number of zeroes before new line

Tags: php, regex

I need to match fixed number of zeroes (which are strings), followed by a new line, and delete it from string.

This is the pattern I'm working on:

```
000000000000000
000000000000000
000000000000000
000100000001000
000010000010000
000001000100000
001000111000100
000100010001000
000010010010000
000001010100000
001000111000100
000100010001000
000010010010000
000001010100000
000000111000000
001111111111100
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000010000000
000000000000000
000000000000000
```

The PHP code is:

```
$regex = '/^[0{' . $amount . '}]\n$/m'; // /^[0{15}]\n$/m
$pattern = preg_replace($regex, null, $pattern); // $pattern is pattern above
```

Comment: fixed question as the pattern and code got parsed really badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the `$` there in regexp (because after `\n` there are digits again.). The square brackets are used for “one of,” you don’t need them here. I doubt also whether you need a “at the very first position” marker `^`. And replacer should be a string:

```
$regex = '/0{' . $amount . '}\n/m'; // /^[0{15}]\n/m
$pattern = preg_replace($regex, '', $pattern); // $pattern is pattern above
```